# preg_replace to preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, php-7

I just upgraded to PHP7 and got this warning :

Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in line 322

How do I replace preg_replace (the second preg_replace in below code) to preg_replace_callback? It's a 3rd party code which I don't really understand. I know some PHP and have tried to look for the solution, but I have trouble understanding it.

```
// Remove HTML Entities //
$string = preg_replace('/&(#?x?[0-9a-z]+)?;/', '', $string); 

$search = array ("'<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>'si",  // Strip out javascript
             "'<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>'si",           // Strip out HTML tags
             "'([\r\n])[\s]+'",                 // Strip out white space
             "'&(quot|#34);'i",                 // Replace HTML entities
             "'&(amp|#38);'i",
             "'&(lt|#60);'i",
             "'&(gt|#62);'i",
             "'&(nbsp|#160);'i",
             "'&(iexcl|#161);'i",
             "'&(cent|#162);'i",
             "'&(pound|#163);'i",
             "'&(copy|#169);'i",
             "'&#(\d+);'e");        

if ($search && $string){
    return preg_replace($search, ' ', $string);        // Line 322, the line that I need to fix
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: the `e` flag doesn't do anything in that case, just remove it.

Comment: Whatever, it seems to be a poorly written code: *(Why removing entities? Why not all entities? Why tags are not removed using `DOMDocument` or `strip_tags`. Why removing indentation except for the first line?)*. Try to understand the goal of this piece of code and rewrite it entirely in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

The /e modifier evaluates PHP code in the replacement string.

Because your code replaces the found strings only with a whitespace, the modifier has no use at all and you can simply remove the `e` in the line `"'&#(\d+);'e");`.

You can find more information on this page: [PHP Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)